# Getting null pointer exception in creating cell in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am getting a null pointer error everytime I ran my code (below) and it points to the line specified with two asterisk.

```
public void writeSomething(XSSFWorkbook wb){
        for (String elem: listOfSheetNames){
            if (elem.equals("Sheet2")){
                sheet = wb.getSheet(elem); //sheet is of type XSSFSheet
                XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
                **XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(1);

                if (cell == null){
                    cell = row.createCell(1);
                    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    cell.setCellValue("Apple");
                }                                       
            }
        }
    }
```

I am a new to apache poi and am just trying to write data to a blank cell in a 2nd excel sheet (Sheet2). Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: What line does the error occur?

Comment: @MichaelArdan Question clearly saying _and it points to the line specified with two asterisk._ ie `**XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(1);`

Comment: @smit Sorry didn't read read the phrase after (below)

Comment: its alright guys... my code actually worked after I placed some random bits of data in 2nd excel sheet. I don't know why that happened. Am just concerned right now that I would keep on doing that everytime I want to write in a new sheet :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the cell is currently `null` not a blank cell. Placing data on the specified sheet makes it blank. You might want to create the cell first then check if it is a `blank` cell rather than `null`.

```
**XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(1);

if (cell == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){
   cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
   cell.setCellValue("Apple");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This would led to incompatible types.

Instead do this:

```
if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    cell.setCellValue("Apple");
}
```