# Null pointer for blank columns and rows using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need help regarding a recurring problem. Earlier I asked a similar question but it was partially answered. Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227108/getting-null-pointer-exception-in-creating-cell-in-apache-poi)
The problem is that everytime I wanted to write on a row that doesn't have any data or blank I always get a null pointer error problem. My temporary solution was to populate those rows with data so I can write something on each column. Also the solution given by one of the volunteers who helped me was only a temporary one. I made a few alterations regarding my code (below).
Null pointer error points to the line with double asterisk.

```
public void writeSomething(XSSFWorkbook wb){
        for (String elem: listOfSheetNames){
            if (elem.equals("Sheet2")){

                sheet = wb.getSheet(elem);
                XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(2);
                **XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(3, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK );

                if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){
                    cell = row.createCell(3);
                    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    cell.setCellValue("this was blank");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I went on to research the problem and I saw that they're using MissingCellPolicy indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929646/how-to-get-an-excel-blank-cell-value-in-apache-poi) I went on to try that code but it doesn't work so I checked on Apache Docs and they have Row.Create_Null_as_Blank but am not sure if it is the same with MissingCellPolicy.Create_Null_as_Blank or the latter was just used in previous poi version. Although this should have solved the problem regarding columns or rows which are blank. I still got a null pointer exception error. I am using Apache poi version 3.9 btw if this helps. Any help is greatly appreciate. Thanks

### UPDATE 1

I updated my code using jims solution. I added a method that will check if a row exists or not. But I still have the same error show with two asterisks. Here is my code:

```
public void writeSomething(XSSFWorkbook wb){
        for (String elem: listOfSheetNames){
            if (elem.equals("Sheet2")){
                int y=1;
                sheet = wb.getSheet(elem); 
                XSSFRow row = null; //create row variable outside if scope

                if (isRowEmpty(sheet.getRow(4))== false){
                    row = sheet.createRow(4);
                }   

                **XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(y, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK );

                if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){
                    cell = row.createCell(y);
                    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    cell.setCellValue("Hooooy this was blank");
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

### isRowEmpty

```
public boolean isRowEmpty(Row row){

        if (row == null){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

### Update 2

I found a workaround for my code just in case someone would find it useful. I didn't use the row.getCell since I always encounter NUll pointer error. See code below

```
public void writeSomething(XSSFWorkbook wb){
        for (String elem: listOfSheetNames){
            if (elem.equals("Sheet2")){
                int y=1; //sets column number
                sheet = wb.getSheet(elem); 
                XSSFRow row = null; //create row variable outside if scope

                if (isRowEmpty(sheet.getRow(19))== false){
                    row = sheet.createRow(19);
                    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(y);
                    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    cell.setCellValue("Hooooy this was blank");
                }   

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: By using following code get the values and do null check

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12529872/1211000

Comment: Hi am just wondering how I could add that lines of code. Because I need to declare first XSSFCell cell = row.getCell... and then check the cell type. But the code stops running when I declare XSSFCell cell so can't check what type of cell it contains.

Comment: use getCellValue(row.getCell(3) method from my posted link//it returns String,check for null.No need again wat cell contains

Comment: Rows can be null too! Are you sure the row you're using exists?

Comment: hi gagravarr i believe the row doesn't exist as well so am gonna try Jims solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the cell you need does not exist you must *create* it with

```
HSSFRow.createCell(int columnIndex, int type)
```

Likewise, if the row does not exist you create it with

```
HSSFSheet.createRow(int rownum)
```

XSSF has identical methods as well.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for answering. Am just wondering what version of Apache POI you're using coz am using version 3.9. I can't find the HSSFSHeet.createRow(int ) method.

Comment: [3.9 javadocs for createRow(int)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#createRow%28int%29)

Comment: hi jim, thanks i found it. I just forgot to answer my own question. However I have edited my code as shown above and the error is still being shown. Thanks for your time

Comment: actually am trying to create row 4 and cell 1 which is y=1. I have this source for that XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(y, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK )

Comment: What is the definition of `isRowEmpty()`? Are you sure it does what you expect?

Comment: hi jim, i placed the code for isRowEmpty. It checks if a row is null and returns value. I tried it on rows that doesn't have data yet and has one and it works.

Comment: `if (isRowEmpty(sheet.getRow(19))== false){ row = sheet.createRow(19);...`  the call to `isRowEmpty()` returns `true` if the row is empty.  You have the test backwards, you want to create the row if `isRowEmpty(...)` returns `true`.  Change the test to just `if (isRowEmpty(sheet.getRow(19))) { ...`